# How do I display a submit button after 3 images are clicked?

Tags: image, button, vote

so I'm running a Runescape Private Server and my java code for voting in it is if the link = www.clearpkz.webs.com/votevote?Username= + username entered is active, then it allows users to do ::claim to get a reward. But how can I make it so the Submit button to enter their username only displays if they click on every image first? Or can I only make it display once every 24 hours even if the page is refreshed?

Here is my current code:

http://pastebin.com/rfQeVkfT

Here is my voting website: [www.clearpkz.webs.com/vote](http://www.clearpkz.webs.com/vote)

Answer (score 0):

You must disable with jQuery a submit function and check if user clicked on image then you can enable a button for submit.

Also:
1. If you show page> $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
2. You need one variable for click test. if user clicked on image COUNTER++
3. If COUNTER > 0 then $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");